# How can i make a smooth Translate animation of image or ImageView?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make a translate animation of Image-view .
I need to translate it over the Y axes with high refresh speed 50 - 100 ms with different directions , 
but its not sliding smooth its just jumps - and i need the image to slide smooth.
 
I tried lots of things but cant make it work. If someone worked with animations or know how to solve my problem please give me a direction, because i am just stacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by increasing and decreasing duration.There is no other way as per i know.It will look bad on emulator but it will look nice on device if you will check.

Comment: Sori Eugine.For my case it worked on device.Are you moving image in straight line or curved path?

Comment: I move it in strait line on Y axes but for different distance each time.

Comment: As per i know it is only possible through changes in duration and initialize values

Comment: smooth animation is not increase speed of animation. some times animations is not continuous. I think we have to set Interpolator to animation.